# How to redirect to login page session expired?

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication

I'm trying to redirect the user to the login page after the session expires, I'm new to type script. I get the following error:

> (TS) Property 'Subscribe' does not exist  on type 'void'

Here is my code:

```
logoff(){
        let result = confirm('¿Desea cerrar sesión?')
        if( result){
            this.snackBar.open('Sesión cerrada correctamente.', 'Cerrar', {
                duration: 3000
            })
            this.userService.logoff().subscribe(() => {this.router.navigate(['/login']) });
        }
    }
```

Comment: That error would occur if `logoff()` does not return an observable. You'll need to show us the definition of `userService.logoff`.

Comment: export class  UserService extends BaseService{
    private user:IUser;

    constructor(
        public http: Http
    ) { 
        super(http, 'user')

        let userObj = sessionStorage.getItem('fs_audio_user')
        if( userObj){
            this.user = <IUser>JSON.parse(userObj);
        }
    }

Comment: public getUser():IUser{
        let userObj = sessionStorage.getItem('fs_audio_user')
        if( userObj){
            this.user = <IUser>JSON.parse(userObj);
            this.user.Extensions = this.user.Extensions || [];
        }else{
            this.user = undefined;
        }

        return this.user;
    }

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the necessary content.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
 logoff() {
        let result = confirm('¿Desea cerrar sesión?')
        if( result){
            this.snackBar.open('Sesión cerrada correctamente.', 'Cerrar', {
                duration: 3000
            })
            this.userService.logoff().subscribe(() => {this.router.navigate(['/login']) });
         }
     }
```

in the UserService the logoff must return an observable

like this:

```
export class UserService {

        private _logout = new Subject();
        logout$ = this._logout.asObservable();


        logoff() {
            /* Some code for logout here*/
            this._logout.next();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This isn't useful, I would imagine there's some further log out actions taking place in `UserService` hence why the local `logoff()` function calls it in the first place. All this will do is redirect them without actually logging them out.

Comment: like this? public getUser():IUser{
        let userObj = sessionStorage.getItem('fs_audio_user')
        if( userObj){
            this.user = <IUser>JSON.parse(userObj);
            this.user.Extensions = this.user.Extensions || [];
        }else{
            this.user = undefined;
        }

        //return (this.user);
        return <IUser>JSON.parse(userObj);
    }